# dynamic variable names using matlab-tables

Tags: matlab

```
HF.EH = EH.Return_EH;
```

I want to do the above statement. HF is a table, so is EH.

```
str = 'HE'
HF.(str) = (str).Return_EH;
```

The last line of code is not working. "HF.(str)" is fine. "(str).Return_EH" is not. How can I make "(str).Return_EH" work?

Right now my code looks like that:

```
EH = importraw('HFRX_Equity_Hedge_Index.csv', 'EH');
EMN = importraw('HFRX_Equity_Market_Neutral_Index.csv', 'EMN');
EDI = importraw('HFRX_Event_Driven_Index.csv', 'EDI');
FICA = importraw('HFRX_FI-Convertible_Arbitrage_Index.csv', 'FICA');
MCTA = importraw('HFRX_Macro_CTA_Index.csv', 'MCTA');
MAI= importraw('HFRX_Merger_Arbitrage_Index.csv', 'MAI');
RVA = importraw('HFRX_Relative_Value_Arbitrage_Index.csv', 'RVA');

% sanity check
if not(isequal(EH.Date, EMN.Date, EDI.Date, FICA.Date, MCTA.Date, MAI.Date, RVA.Date));
 error('Mismatch in Data');
end


% merge Hedgefund Data
HF = array2table(zeros(size(EH,1),8), 'VariableNames',{'Date', ...
                    'EH', 'EMN', 'EDI', 'FICA', 'MCTA', 'MAI', 'RVA'});
HF.Date = EH.Date;                    
HF.EH = EH.Return_EH;
HF.EMN = EMN.Return_EMN;
HF.EDI = EDI.Return_EDI;
HF.FICA = FICA.Return_FICA;
HF.MCTA = MCTA.Return_MCTA;
HF.MAI = MAI.Return_MAI;
HF.RVA = RVA.Return_RVA;
```

I thought there should be a better way.

Comment: I hope for a solution without eval().

Comment: Dynamic variables are a terrible, terrible, terrible idea. I am glad you mention not using `eval` because that is also a terrible terrible idea.  Please tell me you are not using globals!

Comment: :D No I am not using globals

Comment: You don't want dynamic variable names. Dynamic field references in a structure (your working code) is fine, just use that. Why do you want to use dynamic variables anyway?

Comment: Because I am repeating the line over and over again.
    HF.EH = EH.Return_EH;
    HF.EMN = EMN.Return_EMN;
    HF.EDI = EDI.Return_EDI;
    HF.FICA = FICA.Return_FICA;
    HF.MCTA = MCTA.Return_MCTA;
    HF.MAI = MAI.Return_MAI;
    HF.RVA = RVA.Return_RVA;

Comment: What specific situation are you trying to deal with? If you explain more of the context (i.e. what the general problem is that you are trying to solve), I'm sure there's a better solution than what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope this makes clear what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: How did you obtain the right hand side of the last code bit? You shouldn't have created that in the first place, but should've saved directly as the left hand side structure.

Comment: I am reading in several csv files which have multiple columns. (I edited my question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking for dynamic variable names, you can use a structure in the same way you use the table `HF`. First, you would import all data to one structure `S`:

```
S.EH = importraw('HFRX_Equity_Hedge_Index.csv', 'EH');
S.EMN = importraw('HFRX_Equity_Market_Neutral_Index.csv', 'EMN');
% and so on...
```

Then in your sanity check, and everywhere else in your code, you need to add `S.` before this tables. Now you can replace the last part with:

```
fld = fieldnames(S);
for k = 1:numel(fld)
    HF.(fld{k}) = S.(fld{k}).(['Return_' fld{k}]);
end
```